# How Do I Style Shadcn-UI DropdownMenuPortal?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, radix-ui

I currently have the following dropdown menu using shadcn/ui:

```
<DropdownMenuGroup>
    <DropdownMenuSub>
        <DropdownMenuSubTrigger>
            <span>Submenu 1</span>
        </DropdownMenuSubTrigger>
        <DropdownMenuPortal className="z-[501]">
            <DropdownMenuSubContent className="bg-waybase mr-1.5 border-2">
                <DropdownMenuItem className="hover:opacity-75 focus:bg-waybase">
                    <Link
                        href="/submenu1/menu1"
                        className="text-white font-wayfinding w-full h-full"
                    >
                        Menu 1
                    </Link>
                </DropdownMenuItem>
                <DropdownMenuItem className="hover:opacity-75 focus:bg-waybase">
                    <Link
                        href="/submenu1/menu2"
                        className="text-white font-wayfinding w-full h-full"
                    >
                        Menu 2
                    </Link>
                </DropdownMenuItem>
            </DropdownMenuSubContent>
        </DropdownMenuPortal>
    </DropdownMenuSub>
    <DropdownMenuItem className="focus:bg-waybus">
        <Link
            href="/submenu2"
            className="text-white font-wayfinding"
        >
            Submenu 2
        </Link>
    </DropdownMenuItem>
</DropdownMenuGroup>
```

In a page where there is a leaflet map (using React leaflet), this `<DropdownMenuPortal />` gets obstructed by the leaflet map, so what I'm thinking is to set the portal z-index to higher than the leaflet. I've already done `<DropdownMenuPortal className="z-[501]"/>` but it doesn't work. I tried to put the z-index in another place but when I inspect my element in the browser, the tag that controls this z-index is the direct parent of `<DropdownMenuSubContent />`, so I assume it must be the Portal itself

Then, I tried to directly see the content of `dropdown-menu.jsx` and saw this for the portal:

```
const DropdownMenuPortal = DropdownMenuPrimitive.Portal
```

and looking at other dropdown menu that has been modified by shadcn, I to do the same myself to the portal like:

```
const DropdownMenuPortal = React.forwardRef(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
    <DropdownMenuPrimitive.Portal
        ref={ref}
        className={cn("z-[501]", className)}
        {...props}
    />
));
DropdownMenuPortal.displayName = DropdownMenuPrimitive.Portal.displayName;
```

but I don't see any differences.

Could someone guide me from here?